# PyCharm Debugger throws exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) under Python 3.10 if a certain breakpoint is active

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I've written the following sample code in PyCharm to showcase my problem:

```
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(1):
        foo = i + j
        bar = i * j
        print("i={}, j={}".format(i, j))
print("End")
```

If I execute this code in PyCharm in ...

- ... "run" mode, it works fine
- ... "debug" mode without a breakpoint or with a breakpoint at the `foo =`- or `bar =`-statement, it works fine.
- ... "debug" mode with a breakpoint at the `print("i={}, j={}".format(i, j))` statement, it suddenly dumps with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I debugged the last case step by step and saw that after the execution of the `print`-statement in the inner for loop, the debugger jumps back to the inner loop declaration (correct) and then jumps to the `print("i={}, j={}".format(i, j))` statement again instead of jumping out of the inner loop.

I use PyCharm 2022.3.2 Community Edition, Build #PC-223.8617.48, built on January 24, 2023. The active interpreter is based on Python 3.10.9.

Re-installing PyCharm and Python 3.10 didn't solve the problem. Using Python 3.11.1 fixes the issue in this sample code, but in my real code I use the pygame module which doesn't run under 3.11, so that's not an option.

Any ideas/ experiences how to fix this?